# Outlook 365 OAuth login fails with Error in OAuth Server: temporarily_unavailable

Tags: oauth, office365, exchangewebservices

My company develops a web app that requires 3rd party authentication with Outlook 365, to have access mail, calendar and contacts.

We managed to get several users from various tenancies connected through OAuth using the normal OAuth flow and the endpoints:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

But one user constantly fails at login with the error:

```
{
  "line":"398",
  "file":"oauth_server.js",
  "message":"Error in OAuth Server: temporarily_unavailable",
  "time":{"$date":1436988123251},
  "level":"warn"
 }
```

It only happens for his tenancy, and only on our production servers (he can successfully connect with our test servers).

All the settings are analogous for the production app and the test app in the AzureAd portal.

This error states that the microsoft servers are unavailable, yet they manage to connect any other account, which tends to prove that this message is inacurate...

Would anyone have a clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

- I went to the AzureAd management portal,
- went to the configuration page of my app,
- changed the APP ID URI to something random
- saved,
- tried to connect with this account, successfully!
- set back the APP ID URI to its original value.

Still works. I do not know why. Something must have been stuck in the pipe...